# How do screenshots work from a software perspective

Tags: linux, windows, screenshot, microprocessors

How does a screenshot work from a system perspective. I've tried doing some searching, and it seems like all the sites I find are "how do I take a screenshot".

I am more interested in how the operation a screenshot works, Suppose I build my own little device that has a screen, and the data is being displayed on the screen, how would one implement a screenshot (high level, although if you want I suppose an example would be nice), on my device.

EDIT: I see that I had a request to close, I suppose this question is too hard to answer without a very specific context, and perhaps that would eventually be considered out of date, any recommendations on where to post such a question if this is not the right place?

Comment: How high-level or system-specific are you getting at? Usually, all graphics systems eventually blit to a framebuffer. Taking a screen shot amounts to just saving that framebuffer.

Comment: If you want a chance of getting concrete answers, you need to provide a lot more detail, such as what device, what OS, the device hardware configuration (display hardware, driver, etc).

Comment: @onaclov2000 On Windows you can use the GDI to abstract the graphics HW.  You create a memory DC (device context) and bit blit it over from the screen DC.  Not sure how this works on Linux, but I'm quite certain that there is a device abstraction in the XFree86 display driver.

Comment: Thanks you guys, in my particular case it is in fact custom hardware, and it used OpenGL I believe, however beyond that I don't know much, it doesn't have a Screenshot mechanism, and I was kinda interested in how it works to decide if it was worth the effort of investigating. It doesn't have a standard OS that I'm aware of either.

Comment: @yan when you say save that frame buffer, does a conversion have to happen to view it? (I.E. to a JPG or PNG or something format?)

Comment: @onaclov2000, the conversion doesn't need to happen if you don't want to. You'd probably want to PNG or TIFF-encode it if you want to save it on disk, or just blit it back to a screen buffer if you want to view it somewhere else. In the hyper-general, all OpenGL does is render geometry to a 2D bitmap, which is just a memory segment. To "take a screen shot" is to capture that memory and encode it in a way that you can view it later. If you want to display it right away, you can just blit it back out since it'd likely be in the same format you are capturing.

Comment: @yan I would likely want to save it, as it's not a general purpose screen (like a computer screen). sounds interesting, are there "encoding" libraries that take OpenGL memory segments and convert to such things?

Answer (score 2):

This may not be helpful at all, but two of the screenshot utilities I use on a regular basis are open source and fairly short reads:

- The first is [scrot](http://freecode.com/projects/scrot), a simple command line program which takes screenshots using [imlib2](http://freecode.com/projects/imlib2). Both implemented in C.
- The second is the [Chrome Screen Capture](https://code.google.com/p/chrome-screen-capture/) app by Google, implemented in JS/C++.

Comment: I'll have to take a look how they work, I suppose 'read some open source' could be a valid answer (like RTFM)....lol